# How to force login after user browses for a few minutes or browses a few pages?

Tags: login, user-registration

I want users to be redirected to a custom login/registration page after they've got a taste for the site, by time passing or/and browsing a few pages.

I found this code that forces users to login before they can access the site, but im looking for something more specific.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login');

function redirect_to_login(){
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
   // user not logged in so redirect them to login page
   $redirect_url = '' // you can determine where to redirect user after they login
   wp_redirect( wp_login_url($redirect_url), 301 ); exit;
 }
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into `template_redirect` and check a cookie.

Just an idea, not tested:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 't5_force_login_after_time_span' );

function t5_force_login_after_time_span()
{
    $cookie_name = 'first_visit';
    $now         = time();

    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( empty ( $_COOKIE['first_visit'] ) )
    {
        setcookie( $cookie_name, $now, $now + WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
        return;
    }

    $first_visit = (int) $_COOKIE['first_visit'];

    if ( ( $now - $first_visit ) > HOUR_IN_SECONDS )
        auth_redirect();
}
```

Be aware this violates the law in some countries, see the [EU cookie law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications).